# Show bottom tab bar in iPad Safari

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari, mobile-safari, sencha-touch

Is it possible to show a tab bar at the bottom of a webpage, which looks similar to a native app (like button styled)

Something similar to http://www.sencha.com/files/blog/old/assets/images/emails/newsletter/20101207-demo1.png

Also can the same be done using Sencha touch or any other library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

You create a Ext.TabPanel and set the tabBar property to dock bottom.

Something like this:

```
app.views.Viewport = Ext.extend(Ext.TabPanel, {
    tabBar: {
        dock: 'bottom',
        ui: 'dark',
        layout: {
            pack: 'center'
        },
    },
    items: [{
        title: 'item1',
        iconCls: 'someicon'
    }, {
        title: 'item2',
        iconCls: 'someicon'
    }, {
        title: 'item3',
        iconCls: 'someicon'
    }],
   //more config
});
```

Comment: Thx a lot..so if i want the look and feel to resemeble like native app coponent, would u say Sencha touch is the best option or if there are others like jqtouch,etc

Comment: I would say Sencha Touch is the best for making it look like a native app. It even comes with styles that resemble native iOS, Android and Blackberry Themes. It's also very very customizable using SASS. See this link: [Introduction to Theming Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/blog/an-introduction-to-theming-sencha-touch/)